# Rescuing a RoutingError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, I followed José Valim's [blogpost](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/), adding

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

to my application.rb for routing HTTP errors to my own controller.

Everything works just as it's supposed to, my custom error pages work and such, but it throws an `ActionController::RoutingError`though, which gets logged as `FATAL`. Is there anyway to get around that `FATAL`message? I've been trying to rescue from the error both in the application controller and in my error controller, but to no avail.

```
2012-06-27 12:19:33.908 [FATAL] [127.0.0.1] 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/3489423u4023ho")
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a route like `match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"`?

Are you using the production mode, or the development mode?

> You won’t be able to see your custom exceptions in development unless you set `config.consider_all_requests_local` to `false` in your `config/environments/development.rb`. The reason is, if the request is considered local, Rails will always favor to show the debug exceptions page;

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry for not being more specific. Everything works as it should, I'm just trying to get rid of that log message.